# REST API Get single latest resource

Tags: rest

I'm designing a REST api and interested if anyone can help with best practice in the following scenario.

I have...

- GET Customers/{customerId}/Orders - to get all customer orders
- GET Customers/{customerId}/Orders/{orderId} - to get a particular order

I need to provide the ability to get a customers most recent order. What is best practice in this scenario? Simply get all and sort by date or provide a specific method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I need to provide the ability to get a customers most recent order.

Of course you could provide query parameters to filter, sort and slice the orders collection, but why not making it simpler and give the latest order if the client needs it?

You could use something like (returning a representation of a single order):

```
GET /customers/{customerId}/orders/latest
```

The above URL will map an order that will change over the time and it's perfectly fine.

---

> Say there is also a case where you need last 5 orders. How would your route(s) look like?

The above approach focus on the *ability to get a customers most recent order* requirement. If returning the *last 5 orders* requirement eventually comes up after some time, I would probably introduce another mapping such as `/recent` that returns a representation of a collection with the recent orders and accepts a query parameter that indicates the amount of orders to be returned (`5` would be the default value if the parameter is omitted).

The `/latest` mapping would still be valid and would return a representation of the very latest order only.

Providing query parameters to filter, sort and slice the orders collection is still a valid approach.

The key is: If you know the client who will consume the API, target it to their needs. Otherwise, make it more generic. And when modifying the API, be careful with breaking changes and versioning the API is also welcome.

Comment: Say there is **also** a case where you need last 5 orders. How would your route(s) look like?

Comment: Thanks for response. I had to ask because by looking at `orders/latest` it's not clear to me whether I'm getting a single latest order, or all of them sorted by time created. Thus I would argue that sending additional params is clearer. Do you think it all depends on which cases you have? Because OP is asking for "best practice".

Comment: @Traxo For sure the query parameters to filter and sort the orders collection would fit the requirement, but if the client needs just the latest order, why wouldn't I introduce a new enpoint for that? If you know the client who will consume the API, target it to their needs. Otherwise, make it more generic. And when modifying the API, be careful with breaking changes and versioning the API is also welcome :)

Comment: Thanks, IMO feedback you provided is valuable.

Comment: `if the client needs just the latest order, why wouldn't I introduce a new endpoint for that`:
Because where does it end? Next week, the client will need another case-specific endpoint, and next month another one. More and more code, and unique URLs will appear. Using query parameters to filter is much easier, both for your code and for the caller. And when you want to combine some of those filter options, the specific url case would explode, and the filter parameter case is fine.

Answer (score 8):

I think there is no need for another route.

Pass something like `&order=-created_at&limit=1` in your get request

Or  `&order=created_at&orderby=DESC&limit=1` (note I'm not sure about naming your params so maybe you could use `&count=1` instead of `&limit=1`, ditto order params)

I think it also depends whether you are using pagination or not on that route, so perhaps additional params are required

```
Customers/{customerId}/Orders?order=-created_at&limit=1
```

Comment: That's a perfectly valid approach for the scenario described in the question. Hence +1.

Answer (score 2):

The Github API for the similar use case is using latest, to fetch the single resource which is latest.

https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#get-the-latest-release

So to fetch a single resource which is latest you can use.

> GET /customers/{customerId}/orders/latest

However would like to know what community think about this.

IMO the resource/latest gives an impression that the response will be a list of resource sorted by latest to oldest.

Comment: The link to GitHub no longer works. Here is the updated link as of Feb 2024: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/releases/releases?apiVersion=2022-11-28#get-the-latest-release